# Display .icns file in electron renderer process

Tags: javascript, macos, electron

I'm looking for a way to display `.icns` files in electron renderer.

In osx all icons (system icons, applications icons) stored in `.icns` format. I need to show these icons in my electron application.

Currently, when I need to show an icon, I'm converting it to png on-the-fly and show converted result using `<img />` tag.

Problem that it is super slow. Also, since all icons are stored in this format and all apps use it, there should be a fast native way to display them.

Any ideas on how can I use some native APIs to display icns image? Or maybe there is a faster way to show .icns files using electron api?

Comment: did you ever find a solution to this? If not, how are you converting .icns to .png on the fly? Cheers, Morgan

Comment: @MorganR yep, I found a way, you can check out the code [here](https://github.com/KELiON/cerebro-ui/blob/master/src/FileIcon/index.js)

Comment: In the end I used iconutil to convert the .icns into a collection of pngs and used one of those, but I like this too, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a native addon to parse icns file to png or a base64 URL.

```
// In main process
parseIcnsToPNG(icnsPath, pngPath);

// In renderer process
<img src={pngPath}/>
```

https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-icns-ex