# Is there a standard way for an Electron or Node.js app to access system-level icons?

Tags: node.js, electron

I would like to be able to display system-level application and file icons in Electron-based utilities such as launchers and file-inspectors. Is there a standard way for an Electron or Node.js app to access system-level icons?

I have looked in the Electron docs and the closest thing I saw was the entry for [represented files](https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/represented-file) in macOS, but I have not yet seen anything about system-level icons being exposed via the Electron APIs.

If there is a standard cross-platform Electron or Node.js API for loading system-level icon resources for specific applications and files I would love to know about it. Failing that, I welcome suggestions for reading icon resources with other Electron or Node.js APIs.

Edit: Here is a potentially relevant (although platform-specific) question: [Display .icns file in electron renderer process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260151/display-icns-file-in-electron-renderer-process)

Comment: Apart from electron, do you know how to access system-level icons in general?

Comment: @jayarjo I know that macOS stores icons in .icns files a couple levels into app packages and that Windows has .ico files, but there are substantial gaps in my icon-related knowledge, including file format details, conventions on Linux, and relevant best practices. I could probably muster an OS-specific solution, but icon access seems like something that could be broadly useful across apps and platforms, so I am hoping someone with more domain-specific knowledge than I possess might have devised a more solid cross-platform solution.

Answer (score 4):

The most obvious Electron API function is [app.getFileIcon](https://electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetfileiconpath-options-callback) but it seems it can only provide *generic* icons for apps and documents, which may be good enough for your app, or not...

> app.getFileIcon(path[, options], callback)
>
> ```
> path String
>
> options Object (optional)
>
>     size String
>         small - 16x16
>         normal - 32x32
>         large - 48x48 on Linux, 32x32 on Windows, unsupported on macOS.
>
> callback Function
>     error Error
>     icon NativeImage
> ```
>
> Fetches a path's associated icon.
>
> On Windows, there a 2 kinds of icons:
>
> ```
> Icons associated with certain file extensions, like .mp3, .png, etc.
> Icons inside the file itself, like .exe, .dll, .ico.
> ```
>
> On Linux and macOS, icons depend on the application associated with
>   file mime type.

See: [app.getFileIcon() does not return the expected file icon](https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15809)