# Get desktop file icons using NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron, fs

I am trying to create a desktop launcher application in Electron that reads the number of files in the user's desktop and gathers the information from each file found. I am gathering the files and constructing the path based on the directory, but all I can get is the filenames. I am not sure how to store the file itself and extract the desktop icon from it. I haven't seen many solutions to it, other than using the AxtiveXobject however supposedly certain implementations do not work in the latest nodejs. Here is my code so far.

```
//requiring path and fs modules
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
//gets home directory
const homedir = require('os').homedir();
//specifies to desktop
const dir = `${homedir}/Desktop`;
var walk = require('walk');
var filepaths = [];
//storing desktop path
var desktopDir = dir;
console.log(desktopDir);
//gets the desktop files and paths
function getDesktopFiles(_dir){
    //read directory
    fs.readdir(_dir, (err, files) => { 
        if (err) 
          console.log(err); 
        else { 
            files.forEach(_file => { 
            //console.log(_file); 
            let _p = _dir + '/'+_file;
            //changes slashing for file paths
            let _path = _p.replace(/\\/g, "/");
            filepaths.push(_path);

          }) 
        } 
    }) 
    for(let p of filepaths){
        console.log(p);
    }

}

getDesktopFiles(desktopDir);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a function for the same as:

```
function load(icon) {
  if (cache[icon]) return cache[icon];
  return cache[icon] = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/public/icons/' + icon, 'base64');
}
```

[Here](https://github.com/expressjs/serve-index/blob/master/index.js#L451) you can get the inspiration for the same.

Comment: How's this the accepted answer? This does only load graphics from a folder, and doesn't extract icons cross-platform from apps as @tfire09.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick snippet of code which works for me in an Electron renderer process; it has been successfully tested on both macOS and Linux, and should be platform-independent.

It lists all the files located on the user's desktop and displays each file's icon and name at the end of the HTML page; it makes use of the following Electron API functions:

- [app.getPath](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetpathname)
- [app.getFileIcon](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/app#appgetfileiconpath-options)
- [image.toDataURL](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagetodataurloptions)
- [image.getSize](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/api/native-image#imagegetsize)

```
const { app, nativeImage } = require ('electron').remote;
const path = require ('path');
const fs = require ('fs');
//
const desktopPath = app.getPath ('desktop');
let filePaths = fs.readdirSync (desktopPath);
for (let filePath of filePaths)
{
    app.getFileIcon (filePath)
    .then
    (
        (fileIcon) =>
        {
            let div = document.createElement ('div');
            let img = document.createElement ('img');
            img.setAttribute ('src', fileIcon.toDataURL ());
            let size = fileIcon.getSize ();
            img.setAttribute ('width', size.width);
            img.setAttribute ('height', size.height);
            div.appendChild (img);
            div.appendChild (document.createTextNode (" " + path.basename (filePath)));
            // For test purposes, add each file icon and name to the end of <body>
            document.body.appendChild (div);
        }
    );
}
```

You may find some interesting hints about `app.getFileIcon` in the post: [Is there a standard way for an Electron or Node.js app to access system-level icons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55579879/is-there-a-standard-way-for-an-electron-or-node-js-app-to-access-system-level-ic)

Comment: I did not know that electron had built in functions for file icons. I'll make sure to go over their documentation. This actually is a much better implementation than what I managed to bring together. Thank you!